# Calculating time from a given array and selected time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of time which is like

```js
const timeItems =[
        {label: 'Start Time', value: 'Start Time', selected: true},
        {label: '01:00 AM', value: '01:00 AM'},
        {label: '02:00 AM', value: '02:00 AM'},
        {label: '03:00 AM', value: '03:00 AM'},
        {label: '04:00 AM', value: '04:00 AM'},
        {label: '05:00 AM', value: '05:00 AM'},
        {label: '06:00 AM', value: '06:00 AM'},
        {label: '07:00 AM', value: '07:00 AM'},
        {label: '08:00 AM', value: '08:00 AM'},
        {label: '09:00 AM', value: '09:00 AM'},
        {label: '10:00 AM', value: '10:00 AM'},
        {label: '11:00 AM', value: '11:00 AM'},
        {label: '12:00 PM', value: '12:00 PM'},
        {label: '01:00 PM', value: '01:00 PM'},
        {label: '02:00 PM', value: '02:00 PM'},
        {label: '03:00 PM', value: '03:00 PM'},
        {label: '04:00 PM', value: '04:00 PM'},
        {label: '05:00 PM', value: '05:00 PM'},
        {label: '06:00 PM', value: '06:00 PM'},
        {label: '07:00 PM', value: '07:00 PM'},
        {label: '08:00 PM', value: '08:00 PM'},
        {label: '09:00 PM', value: '09:00 PM'},
        {label: '010:00 PM', value: '10:00 PM'},
        {label: '011:00 PM', value: '11:00 PM'},
        {label: '012:00 AM', value: '12:00 AM'}
      ];
```

Now, i am getting selected start time and end time from the user. For example i'm getting start time `09:00 AM` to end time `11:00 AM`. Now here's the duration is (by hour)`2`. I need to get that for every different selection considering `AM` & `PM`. How can i calculate that?

Here's what i have tried till now:

```js
var startIndex = timeItems.findIndex(x => x.label === '09:00 AM');
var endIndex = timeItems.findIndex(x => x.label === '11:00 AM');
console.log(endIndex- startIndex);
```

But it won't work on different AM and PM scenario.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Writing what you tried helps answering questions easier...

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: It can't be considered a try. I think you should convert PM to 24-hour format, and that make simple math. If the minutes is always "00", use parsInt to get the hour part. If minutes change too, use split(':') and calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to parse the times (not including validation code)

```js
const timeItems =[
        {label: 'Start Time', value: 'Start Time', selected: true},
        {label: '01:00 AM', value: '01:00 AM'},
        {label: '02:00 AM', value: '02:00 AM'},
        {label: '03:00 AM', value: '03:00 AM'},
        {label: '04:00 AM', value: '04:00 AM'},
        {label: '05:00 AM', value: '05:00 AM'},
        {label: '06:00 AM', value: '06:00 AM'},
        {label: '07:00 AM', value: '07:00 AM'},
        {label: '08:00 AM', value: '08:00 AM'},
        {label: '09:00 AM', value: '09:00 AM'},
        {label: '10:00 AM', value: '10:00 AM'},
        {label: '11:00 AM', value: '11:00 AM'},
        {label: '12:00 PM', value: '12:00 PM'},
        {label: '01:00 PM', value: '01:00 PM'},
        {label: '02:00 PM', value: '02:00 PM'},
        {label: '03:00 PM', value: '03:00 PM'},
        {label: '04:00 PM', value: '04:00 PM'},
        {label: '05:00 PM', value: '05:00 PM'},
        {label: '06:00 PM', value: '06:00 PM'},
        {label: '07:00 PM', value: '07:00 PM'},
        {label: '08:00 PM', value: '08:00 PM'},
        {label: '09:00 PM', value: '09:00 PM'},
        {label: '010:00 PM', value: '10:00 PM'},
        {label: '011:00 PM', value: '11:00 PM'},
        {label: '012:00 AM', value: '12:00 AM'}
      ];
      
function diff(start, end) {
  const amOrPmEnd = end.substring(end.length - 2);
  let endInt = parseInt(end.split(amOrPmEnd)[0]);
  if (amOrPmEnd === 'PM' && endInt !== 12) {
     endInt += 12;
  }
  const amOrPmStart = start.substring(start.length - 2);
  let startInt = parseInt(start.split(amOrPmStart)[0]);
  if (amOrPmStart === 'PM' && startInt !== 12) {
     startInt += 12;
  }
  return endInt - startInt;  
}

console.log(diff("12:00 PM", "01:00 PM"))
console.log(diff("2:00 AM", "03:00 PM"))
console.log(diff("01:00 PM", "011:00 PM"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do, create a temporary `Date()` object which the Start and End time which you get from your selection, the `Date()` constructor need Day as well as Time, so you can just add any arbitrary date to both to Date constructor as it won't matter.

Attaching a code snippet which can find the difference between two given Times.

```js
var timeStart = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "05:00 AM");
var timeEnd = new Date("01/01/2007 " + "10:30 PM");

var diff = (timeEnd - timeStart) / 60000; //dividing by seconds and milliseconds

var minutes = diff % 60;
var hours = (diff - minutes) / 60;
console.log(hours);
```